# GRUB not detecting my windows partiton

Tags: debian, boot, dual-boot, grub

I've been trying to get a windows dual boot running but GRUB is being a bit of a pain at the moment. I can boot into Debian from the boot menu but 
Windows is nowhere to be seen.

Boot-info : http://paste.ubuntu.com/24698360/

I've tried running "update-grub" and "os-prober" from inside Debian but had no luck with it. "os-prober" did detected a widows recovery partion.

I booted up a boot-repair image and repaired the MBR because I really wanted to use a windows program (Windows booted fine this time) and then again repaired GRUB after that. There is no option in the boot menu for Windows.

All comments are appreciated.
-Write

Comment: Are you using UEFI or BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

This solution can maybe help you:

```
~# grub-install /dev/[BOOT PARTITION]
~# grub-update
```

source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/661947/add-windows-10-to-grub-os-list#661983

Comment: Which Partition is the [BOOT PARTITION] ? Debian ?

Comment: grub-install do it automatically, you can do `grub-install /dev/sdx && grub-update` replace sdx with your volume.

Comment: Can you show  `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS` in Debian and `dmidecode -t0`

Comment: Just to save a couple of minute to the non-expert like me, I think it's `update-grub`, and you need to run with `sudo`. `grub-update` is unknown for me (Xubuntu 20.04).